# Elasticsearch & Fuzzy don't search on all fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I try to do a cool searchbar with elasticsearch and fuzzy query.
In my model, this is how I index fields :

```
 mapping do
 indexes :id,    index: :not_analyzed
 indexes :name,  analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 80
 indexes :brief, analyzer: 'snowball'
 indexes :media, analyzer: 'snowball'
 indexes :owner, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 70
 indexes :tags, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 60
end
```

and a method `to_indexed_json` to index as json and downcase all values.

In my controller, I have this :

in my search method:

```
fuzzy_query = { "query" => {
             "match" => {
              "_all" => {
                "query" => params[:search],
                "operator" => 'or',
                "fuzziness" => 'AUTO'
             }
            }
          }
        }

 s = Tire.search 'campaigns/campaign', payload: fuzzy_query
```

I got some good results, but only on the 'name' field.
Other fields doesn't work.

Is anyone has an idea ?

thanks !

Comment: Please look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37988403/2393924